# Unable to change to native resolution

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

Using Ubuntu 14.04, I am unable to change my monitors resolution to its highest native supported resolution: 1920x1080. It is instead stuck on 1024x768.

After booting, and after LightDM first starts, I see that it is the correct/desired resolution (1920x1080), however after a second the screen flashes black and resizes to 1024x768. After this, I am unable to change my resolution back to what I want it to be. Even after logging in and going into the "Screen Display" settings, all I see is "Unknown Display" and two resolutions listed: 1024x768 and 800x600.

`xrandr` does not help and does not list any resolutions apart from the aforementioned two (1024x768, 800x600). I have tried following [this tutorial](http://www.sudo-juice.com/lightdm-resolution/) and [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=611851) to add a new mode using `xrandr` to no avail.

I am using a single monitor setup (Acer V233HL) **connected via VGA**, and the nouveau drivers (nvidia drivers make no difference, either) on an NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT.

- `$ uname -a`
  `Linux COMPUTER 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08
  UTC x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `$ lspci`

  [pastebin of output](http://pastebin.com/r8EUdyWi)
- `$ lsmod`

  [pastebin of output](http://pastebin.com/jhUQnE2D)
- `$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

  [pastebin of output](http://pastebin.com/8R5XZ60j)
- `$ dmesg`

  [pastebin of output](http://pastebin.com/hHCiqvfh)

Cheers guys! :-)